# Extracting data with preg_match

Tags: facebook, preg-match

I'm trying to extract Facebook members name with preg_match from gaph.facebook.com, by userID. The script doesn't seem to be working. can anyone help?

```
    <?php   
$content = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/myid?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture');

preg_match("'\"name\": \"(.*?)\",'si", $content, $match);
$name = $match[1];

?>
```

Comment: What doesn't seem work? What do you obtain?

Comment: Well $name doesn't return anything

Comment: Could you show an extract of `$content`, maybe there're no `"name": "...",` in it?

Comment: You could put in any Facebook ID, but here is an example https://graph.facebook.com/sarah.casey?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Try displaying the value in $content to make sure it's getting correctly set.
Also, wouldn't it be easier to use the JSON decoder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why would you use PHP `preg_match()` with `REGEX` instead of using `json_decode()` since you're already dealing with a `JSON` type response

```
<?php 
     $content = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/{ID}?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture');

     $jsonData = json_decode($content);

     echo '</br> id: '         .$jsonData->id,
          '</br> name: '       .$jsonData->name,
          '</br> first_name: ' .$jsonData->first_name,
          '</br> last_name: '  .$jsonData->last_name,
          '</br> picutre url: '.$jsonData->picture->data->url;    
?>
```

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oaPYIU)